# Why can I not call Select() from a CaptureCollection object?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a terrible feeling this may reduce itself to a dummy-on-me, forest-for-trees situation, and if that's the case, mea culpa in advance. But for the life of me I'm just not understanding why the following line will not compile in C#, assuming `myRegEx` is a `RegEx` object and `myString` is the target for a call to the `Match` method, as follows:

```
String[] results = myRegEx.Matches(myString)[0].Groups["Group1"].Captures.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray<String>();
```

The `.Captures` reference should get me to the `CaptureCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable`, and `IEnumerable` offers an extension method `Select` for a transform as I've attempted here, snagging the `Value` property for each item in the collection and pushing it into a string array.

However, the compiler barks at me with

> 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection does not contain a
>   definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   System.Text.RegularExpression.CaptureCollection' could be found.

I can overcome this by calling the `.Cast<Capture>()` method from the Captures object, and then call select with a transform that, in turn, accesses the `Value` property, but that seems a little silly considering the objects already *are* `Capture` objects.

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance for pointing out what must be a painfully obvious oversight on my part.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. MatchCollection and CaptureCollection implement only `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: AAAAARRRRRGGGHHH!!!!!!!! Of course. Thank you. Post that as answer and I'll be glad to accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. *MatchCollection* and *CaptureCollection* implement only `IEnumerable` interface not `IEnumerable<T>`

That is why you need `Cast<T>` `or OfType<T>`